# Javascript Date and time

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

What I'm trying to achieve is to get an array of dates from a start date to an end date, along with the seconds of each particular date along with the minute in seconds so that I can easily validate if there is a way that I can work around it and it prints milliseconds instead of every hour so it's easy to validate

```
      <script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
      const startDateSchedule = "2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z"
      const endDateSchedule = "2020-01-12T00:00:00.000Z"

      const date = function dateRange(startDate, endDate, steps = 1) {
        const dateArray = [];
        const currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  
        while (currentDate <= new Date(endDate)) {
          dateArray.push(new Date(currentDate));
          currentDate.setUTCDate(currentDate.getUTCDate() + steps);
        }
  
        return dateArray;
      }
      const dates = date(startDateSchedule, endDateSchedule);
      console.log(dates);

      const hours = [];
      for(let minute = 0; minute < 24; minute++) {
          hours.push(moment({ hour }).format('h:mm A'));
      }

      const addItemEvery = (arr, el) =>
        arr.reduce((res, v) => [...res, v, el], []);
      const AllDate = addItemEvery(dates, hours);


     "alldate": [
    "2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-11T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-12T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-14T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-17T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-19T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-02-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-02-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-02-06T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-02-07T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ],
    "2020-02-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    [
        "12:00 AM",
        "1:00 AM",
        "2:00 AM",
        "3:00 AM",
        "4:00 AM",
        "5:00 AM",
        "6:00 AM",
        "7:00 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "12:00 PM",
        "1:00 PM",
        "2:00 PM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "4:00 PM",
        "5:00 PM",
        "6:00 PM",
        "7:00 PM",
        "8:00 PM",
        "9:00 PM",
        "10:00 PM",
        "11:00 PM"
    ]
]
```

so instead of having this hour, I want to have the list of milliseconds of all the days in a milliseconds format

Comment: Can you explain better your problem please? I don't understand what do you want like result, can you create a little example of input and output?

Comment: So for every day you want an array of 86400000 elements? Once for every millisecond of the day? Or 24 element, one for every hours of the day, write in milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try with this code, I'm not sure if this is what did you mean.

```js
const date = function dateRange(startDate, endDate, steps = 1) {
  const dateArray = [];
  const currentDate = moment(startDate);

  while (currentDate.isSameOrBefore(moment(endDate))) {
    dateArray.push(moment(currentDate).format());

    const hoursInMs = [];
    for (let hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) hoursInMs.push(moment(currentDate).add(hour, 'hours').format('x'));

    dateArray.push(hoursInMs);

    currentDate.add(steps, 'day');
  }

  return dateArray;
};

const startDateSchedule = '2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z';
const endDateSchedule = '2020-01-12T00:00:00.000Z';

const dates = date(startDateSchedule, endDateSchedule);

console.log(dates);

// "2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z",
// [ '1578441600000',
//   '1578445200000',
//   '1578448800000',
//   '1578452400000',
//   '1578456000000',
//   '1578459600000',
//   '1578463200000',
//   '1578466800000',
//   '1578470400000',
//   '1578474000000',
//   '1578477600000',
//   '1578481200000',
//   '1578484800000',
//   '1578488400000',
//   '1578492000000',
//   '1578495600000',
//   '1578499200000',
//   '1578502800000',
//   '1578506400000',
//   '1578510000000',
//   '1578513600000',
//   '1578517200000',
//   '1578520800000',
//   '1578524400000' ],
// "2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z",
// [ '1578528000000',
//   '1578531600000',
//   '1578535200000',
//   '1578538800000',
//   '1578542400000',
//   '1578546000000',
//   '1578549600000',
//   '1578553200000',
//   '1578556800000',
//   '1578560400000',
//   '1578564000000',
//   '1578567600000',
//   '1578571200000',
//   '1578574800000',
//   '1578578400000',
//   '1578582000000',
//   '1578585600000',
//   '1578589200000',
//   '1578592800000',
//   '1578596400000',
//   '1578600000000',
//   '1578603600000',
//   '1578607200000',
//   '1578610800000' ],
// ... ]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```